# How to check whether Bing Advertisment returns error code / is not active?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a Windows 8 application (C#/XAML) and added advertising with the Bing Advertising SDK.

Sometimes when there are no ads to display, the space is empty. Can I programmatically check whether there is advertising present?

My Problem: My app just didn't get certified, because of missing functionality - I added a button to hide the advertisement via InApp-Purchase (just to test that) and I think that they do not like having a button which does not reference to an ad.